# Is there a simple way to execute a method on the UI thread during an asynchronous task?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

During the lengthy execution of an asynchronous method, launched with `Task.Run()` I might need to get back to the user for additional input or confirmation, e.g. a message box or a file dialog which has to be executed on the UI thread.

Is there a simple way to do this?

```
private void buttonApply_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    // ...
    await executeAsync (_cts.Token, progress);
  } catch (OperationCanceledException) { }    
  // ...
}

private async Task executeAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<string> progress) { 
  // ...      
  await Task.Run (() => execute (path, cancellationToken, progress), cancellationToken);
}

private void execute (string path, CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<string> progress) {
  // do some work, report progress, check for cancellation
  // --> depending on initial work, request additional input via UI thread, how?
  // do more work, based on initial work and requested input
}
```

Comment: You can Invoke a DialogBox in your execute function

Comment: Well, you can abuse `IProgress` for that too. Create `Progress<more_elaborate_struct>` instead of `Progress<string>`, call `Report()` on it with a parameter that will mean "Display some UI", and in the `ProgressChanged` event handler display the UI if the passed object is *something*. It will be displayed on the UI thread.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your comments, they pointed me to the right direction. I looked into the implementation of `System.Progress<T>` and I think, I will start from there.

`System.Progress<T>` captures the `SynchronizationContext` and `Report(T value)` invokes the asynchronous `Post()` method of the sync context.

Since I need feedback from my invocation, I will go for the synchronous `Send()` method instead and presumably base this on a new interface, `ICallbackQuery<T, TResult>` or something like that, modeled after `IProgress<T>` and `Progress<T>`

Comment: This is likely the best solution; there's nothing built-in for these kinds of back-queries. I have a [`PauseToken`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/PauseToken.cs) that may also be useful in the implementation of this interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework called ReactiveUI - it uses ReactiveExtensions and observables to make MVVM life easier.

You don't have deep dive and use the whole framework, but it has a neat concept of [Interaction](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/interactions/):

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly Interaction<string, bool> confirm;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.confirm = new Interaction<string, bool>();
    }

    public Interaction<string, bool> Confirm => this.confirm;

    public async Task DeleteFileAsync()
    {
        var fileName = ...;

        // this will throw an exception if nothing handles the interaction
        var delete = await this.confirm.Handle(fileName);

        if (delete)
        {
            // delete the file
        }
    }
}

public class View
{
    public View()
    {
        this.WhenActivated(
            d =>
            {
                d(this
                    .ViewModel
                    .Confirm
                    .RegisterHandler(
                        async interaction =>
                        {
                            var deleteIt = await this.DisplayAlert(
                                "Confirm Delete",
                                $"Are you sure you want to delete '{interaction.Input}'?",
                                "YES",
                                "NO");

                            interaction.SetOutput(deleteIt);
                        }));
            });
    }
}
```

You can just focus on Interactions.

I would also recommend ReactiveCommand to avoid problems with buttons and async actions.